# My terms in Google Account 0Auth signup flow?

Tags: google-authentication

Newbie here. Does anyone know if I can add my site's terms to the google 0Auth Account setup flow?
Otherwise, I need another T&C's acceptance in my flow.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a link to your TOS in the [GCP Oauth](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en) page for your project. See the "User Consent" section on the help page.